# How to get each values from listview page and set each to another page each widgets in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When I initially tab the textformfields it goes to the list view screen and I need to get each items on tapping the listview and set each items in each textformfields in another page in flutter.

**Code**

```
TextFormField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  onTap: () {                      
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => search_questions()),
                    );
                  },
                  readOnly: true,
                  enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                    labelText: 'Secure Question #1',
                    hintText: todo,
                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                    filled: true,
                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded,
                        color: Color(0xff1946ba),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),  


//listview
 Widget _listView() {
    return new Flexible(
      child: new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: _socialListItems.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Container(
              height: 30.0,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 50.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => login1(
                          initialPage: 2,
                        ),
                        settings: RouteSettings(
                          name: _socialListItems[index], // ),
                        ),
                      ));
                  // Navigator.pop(context, _socialListItems[index]);
                },
                child: new Text(
                  "${_socialListItems[index]}",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Please find the below image attachment.

[listview item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6KkJ.jpg)

[login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3qJ7.jpg)

Comment: Can you update your question with a short code example? It will make it easier for us to understand and answer your question.

Comment: @Devilscomrade I am new to stack overflow. Here above I added the coding line. So don't mistaken me and please try to help me.